# Push input text into jQuery and go to URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a demonstration area where I can show clients what their mockups (in sub domains) will look like.

The area where the demos will be, will always be the same.

The demos sites names correspond to the actual name of the site being redeveloped.

I am putting together a form where a user can type in their site name and the page will redirect to the subdomain where the demo site is.

I have it mostly done, however, my jquery skills are not the best and I am in a quandary at the moment. If you look at my code I have apple as the name (keyword) and it goes to apple.com. However the idea is to "push" the name from the field, into the address, like:

```
window.location.href = "https://insertedname.nameofsitearea.com/";
```

Inserted name will come from the input and, the (I changed the name of the domain) nameofsitearea is where the subdomains are.

That way I dont need an array of names, the only thing needed is an actual subdomain and that will dynamically be always current; obviously dependent on the subdomain being active.

Here is the code I have right right now (I tried to add arrays but it errored out, probably because of the way I was writing it, but as I said my skills... :( )

This would probably be much nicer with a jquery modal but I can only implement what I know how to do, sorry.

Code I'm using;

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div>
<form method="get" id="proceed">
    <label>Please enter the site name<br><sup>[dot] names invalid</sup></label><br>
    <input type="text" name="proceed" id="proceed_texto"  placeholder="Proceed to site"/>
</form>
</div>

<script>

$("#proceed").on("submit", function(event){     

// prevent form from being submitted
event.preventDefault();

// get value of text box using .val()
name = $("#proceed_texto").val();

// compare lower case, as you don't know what they will enter into the field
if (name.toLowerCase() == "apple")
{
    // redirect the user.. 
    window.location.href = "https://apple.com";
    // need to redirect to subdomain based on name
}
else
{
    alert("\u2297 Sorry, demo site unavailable.. \n--------------------------------------\nError variables:\n\u2022 Any [dot] addition not valid.\n   EG: ( .com  .net  .org )\n--------------------------------------\n\t\u2022 Name entered was incorrect\n\t\u2022 Name entered was misspelled\n\t\u2022 The site does not exist\n\t\u2022 The site is now live\n--------------------------------------\nSubmitted \u2666 " + name + " ");
}
});

</script>
```

Hope this makes sense....

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do something like this? I added the part of looking to see if it is in an array.

```
// get value of text box using .val()
name = $("#proceed_texto").val();
names = ["apple", "other"]
// compare lower case, as you don't know what they will enter into the field
if (names.indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
{
    // redirect the user.. 
    window.location.href = "https://" + name.toLowerCase() + ".com";
    // need to redirect to subdomain based on name
}
```

Comment: I wanted to get away from an array (as I mentioned earlier) that way its totally dependant upon what sub-domains are actually in place - all others throw the error msg. This means I would be constantly having to edit the file as new or disabled areas are created.

Comment: How do you want to verify it as a real domain? Some options are, DNS lookup, database, just regex bad characters out and give it a go.

Comment: I wasn't trying to verify if it's real or not - all I was trying to do is, if its there, go to it if not - show the error. I didn't want to overcomplicate it with too much stuff.

Comment: I got this working using the array ( which I really don't want to use - but it looks like I have no other choice )    I added this after the error codes :    // alert("Site unavailable..(entered: " + name + ")");
        alert("\u2297 Sorry, demo site unavailable..\nSubmitted \u2666 " + name + " ");
        location.reload();
        window.location.reload(true);

Comment: I realize now I may have to use the array method as it has to check the domain to see if the area exists and then return the result - and that takes way toooo long. Whereas with the array (my not seeing the trees for the forest) simply executes to the domain if the array compares to the entry *name then applied... it does show the error - I added a refresh window after the click to make sure the field does not retain previous entry. All I need to do now is add it to the page and make it look "pretty"

Answer (score 0):

You've just gotta create a new URL using the value you grabbed.

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div>
<form method="get" id="proceed">
    <label>Please enter the site name<br><sup>[dot] names invalid</sup></label><br>
    <input type="text" name="proceed" id="proceed_texto"  placeholder="Proceed to site"/>
</form>
</div>

<script>

$("#proceed").on("submit", function(event){     

    // prevent form from being submitted
    event.preventDefault();

    // get value of text box using .val()
    const name = $("#proceed_texto").val().toLowerCase();
    const url = 'https://' + name + '.nameofsitearea.com';

    $.ajax(url)
        .fail(() => {
        alert('error message...')
    })
        .done(() => {
        window.location.href = 'https://' + name + '.nameofsitearea.com';
    })

});

</script>
```

Comment: This works but the errors (I need them for my older clients) dont apply - yes you havnt added them - so I added mine to your snippet, but it broke - bummer

Comment: The only way I know of to check if a page exists using JS is by using AJAX, but the page you're checking would need to be on the same domain as yours or it'll return an error every time (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: Check edits for how you could do it from the same domain.

Comment: Yes this field is going to be on the same domain as part of the landing/info page. The user (in this case clients) will go to their respective subdomains, provided they type in the right subdomain name.

Comment: Try out that code and let me know if it works. What it’s doing is sending an asynchronous call to the potential page. If it can’t find it, the call will fail which is handled with the `.fail` method. If it finds it, it will runs the `.done` method and load the page.

Comment: I put that page in the public_html area and ran it as you said - it does not work - it simply resets itself and the url shows as thus: https://demothewebsite.com/goto.html?proceed=delmarviewdental